# MYSQL Case with inner join

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT 
  Dag AS Dag,
  CASE
    Jaar 
    WHEN 2013 
    THEN Levering 
  END AS '2013',
  CASE
    Jaar 
    WHEN 2014 
    THEN Levering 
  END AS '2014' 
FROM
  tbl_Levering 
  INNER JOIN tbl_EParameter 
    ON (Maand = tbl_EParameter.ZMaand) 
ORDER BY Dag
```

The output give two records for each day of that month. In the first record the value of `2013`and in the second row the value of `2014`. I want to have one record.

What do I wrong in the statement.

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you are asking. 
But note that CASE can not be used to change the column name.

Could show you expect to get?

What you want is this you?

```
SELECT 
   Jaar AS 'Year', 
   AS Dag Dag 
FROM 
   tbl_Levering 
   INNER JOIN tbl_EParameter 
     ON (Maand = tbl_EParameter.ZMaand) 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick use `max` with group by so that you will have one row per dag and result for 2013 ,2014 in two separate columns if you don't use max then group by results are indeterminate and any of row from same group will be picked in end results

```
SELECT 
  Dag AS Dag,
  MAX(CASE
    Jaar 
    WHEN 2013 
    THEN Levering 
  END) AS '2013',
  MAX(CASE
    Jaar 
    WHEN 2014 
    THEN Levering 
  END) AS '2014' 
FROM
  tbl_Levering 
  INNER JOIN tbl_EParameter 
    ON (Maand = tbl_EParameter.ZMaand) 
GROUP BY Dag
ORDER BY Dag
```

Comment: With the MAX I get indeed one record, but only the record of the last day of the month and not the other days of the month.

Answer (score 0):

I like to add a picture but that is not allowed for me a this moment.

The table have the following fields
Jaar , Maand, Dag, Levering
So for every day in the month I have one record with the delivery in kHw for my solarpanels

In the query I want for month 6, value stored in tbl_EParameter.Zmaand the record from 2013 and 2014, like this

Dag 2013  2014
1    5     4,5
2    6,8   3,2
etc, etc